# how do i make a 9x9 grid with predetermined numbers for sudoku?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi im currently working on a school project where i have to make an android application. i choose to make a sudoku and since im a newbie in java and android im having some problems making a 9x9 grid with pre determined numbers in it. ive tried the built in method gridview but its only giving me problems.As im not a very skilled java user im going to make it with predetermined numbers with a already done sudoku game to check if the numbers in the grids are correct.
 so here is my question how do i make a 9x9 gridview with predetermined numbers in it and making it fit into my android application.
If these questions seems stupid i apologize since i just started working with java and android .

Comment: "ive tried the built in method gridview but its only giving me problems"  What problems?  GridView is probably the way to go

Comment: I think you should try to analyse a ready example before: http://code.google.com/p/opensudoku-android/

Comment: i tried making a 9column gridview and i tried resizing it abit. it got weird and changed it self somehow and im abit unsure on how to set variables in the gridview and being able to change the empty ones with a textview or something. Like i said im a newbie and i started with android a month ago.